# Как заставить изображение между двумя блоками оставаться на месте

Tags: html, css

Не знаю как правильно задать вопрос. Проблема в следующем: есть два блока стык между ними закрывает фоновое изображение нужно сделать так что-бы это изображение при адаптации не смещалось
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот тут начальная позиция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а тут при уменьшении
Если убрать contain то она останется на месте но не будет адаптироваться
Подскажите какие есть варианты

```css
.section4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: -o-radial-gradient(rgba(207, 130, 79, 0.77), #512112);
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(207, 130, 79, 0.77), #512112);
}

.section4__bg1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -65px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("img/bg_block4_down.png") no-repeat center bottom/contain;
  z-index: 1;
}

.section5 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: -o-radial-gradient(rgba(253, 176, 24, 0.66), #fdb11a);
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(253, 176, 24, 0.66), #fdb11a);
}
```

```html
<section class="section4">
  <div class="section4__bg1"></div>
</section>
<section class="section5">

</section>
```

Как изображение добавить не знаю

Comment: ответ будет зависеть от того, как вы организовали позиционирование изображения. добавьте в вопрос модельный код

Comment: Добавил код только как картинку добавить не знаю

Comment: Переделайте все эти div и section на один div с множественным background.

Comment: А если блоков 5? Для всех один? И как это примерно выглядит? Можете фрагмент не большой написать?